# Trying to create a excel worksheet using data from a VBA form then adding it to end of workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a excel worksheet using data from a VBA form then adding it to end of workbook. Please help to activate the code

```
Private Sub Add_Tab_Click()

   Dim txtNameSur As Worksheet
   
   Set txtNameSur = Worksheets("Me.Textbox1")
    
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Newname = Worksheets.Add.Name = Userform1.txtNameSur.Value
    
    ActiveSheet.Name = Newname
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is this line `Set txtNameSur = Worksheets("Me.Textbox1")` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @SJR He probably meant to use the text in Textbox1 as worksheet name: `Worksheets(Me.Textbox1)`

Answer (score 0):

The goal in your question is a bit unclear, but I guess you meant to do something like below:

```
Private Sub Add_Tab_Click()

    'copy first worksheet to the end of the workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    
    'set the copied worksheet to a variable `NewWorksheet`
    Dim NewWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set NewWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 'last one is the copied one
    
    'give it a new name (use the text in Textbox1 as name)
    NewWorksheet.Name = Me.Textbox1.Text

End Sub
```